# Android studio Version 3 Not Using Master Password

Tags: android, android-studio, passwords

Android Studio Version 3 seems to have changed the way Master Passwords are used and I cannot get them to work.  I had no problem with Version 2.  In Version 2, the
Settings -> System Settings -> Passwords
gave 3 storage policies to choose from:

- Do not remember,
- remember until app closed
- save on disk with master password.

The last of these has worked for me.

Under version 3, the only options are Save in KeePass and Do Not Save.
I have chosen Save in KeePass, set the location and set a master password, but when I generate a signed APK, it does not prompt for the master password, it just prompts for the Key Store Password, and does this every time I generate anew signed APK, even though Remember Passwords is checked.

Any ideas how I can get this to work as with version 2, where I just need to enter the master password once per session?

Comment: is your problem still exists?

Comment: Yes, still a problem.

Comment: I have upvoted the question. Let's see if someone knew the answer to this question.